# EWS: How to get CRM ID from Outlook?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, dynamics-crm-online

I have been looking for a way to retrieve CRM ID from Outlook. CRM ID is extended [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633697(v%3Dexchg.80)). We have D365 and Outlook and enabled server-side sync for Contact. We have custom logic and to work properly we need to identify the source of records Outlook or D365.

We use Graph API subscription mechanism and when we receive notification object we have only Id of contact created in outlook even if this record comes from D365 by server-side exchange sync. The main idea is to distinguish records originally created in Outlook and created by integration from CRM.

If there is any property that can help us fulfill this requirement. Unfortunately, CRM ID is visible in Outlook UI, but not accessible in EWS API/Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

If its an extended MAPI property then all you need to do in either EWS or the Graph API is define and access it like the link you pointed to outlined (or if this the graph use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0 ). Have you tried this ? I would probably suggest you start by using a MAPI editor like MFCMapi or OutlookSpy to look at an Item in a Mailbox where the property is available this will give you the correct information you need to either define the property in EWS or the Graph